# Facebook App Admin cannot post Live Video API request on its own page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, video, live-streaming

I'm using the Facebook Live Video API for testing purpose.
I've created a Test User, associated with my Facebook App, with the following permissions: publish_actions, user_videos, publish_pages, manage_pages

Using graph API explorer, I can make a POST request on /{user_id}/live_videos, using the Test User ID and Access Token (got it from the My App -> Role -> Test Users).

But, if I create a page with the Test User (logged in with its email), POST resquest on  /{page_id}/live_videos, with the test user page ID and Page Access Token with required permissions, I get an error:

```
"message": "(#100) No permission to perform current operation.",
"type": "OAuthException",
"code": 100,
```

I have the exact same issue when I'm not using a Test User, i.e. when I try to post live videos on a page id with an admin page token, while it works on its user id with user access token.

I've followed these documentation:
[Live Video API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/live_videos/)

Why can't I POST live_videos on page ID with a page access token while it works on user ID with user access token?

Best regards.

Nico

Answer (score 1):

POSTing a live_video with the page access token should work now. After chatting with the engineers at FB, they fixed the problem, so it wasn't an issue with just you.